# solana-test-validator error: 'Incompatible CPU detected: missing AVX support'

Tags: validator, solana-test-validator, testvalidator

I'm trying to run `solana-test-validator` on:

- Windows 11 host
- Running Virtual Box 6.1.38
- With Ubuntu 22.04.1 guest
- Razer Blade 14, 8 Core AMD CPU, RTX 3080, 16Gb

It worked fine a few weeks ago, I'm not sure what changed, not much (maybe a Virtual Box update?), now I get this error:

```
Aborted (core dumped) 
Incompatible CPU detected: missing AVX support.
```

I've tried MANY things to fix this, nothing has worked.

Including...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780506/how-to-enable-avx-avx2-in-virtualbox-6-1-16-with-ubuntu-20-04-64bit

- Disable Hyper-v in Windows
- bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
- DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
- Turning on AVX2 in VirtualBox guest: https://mzh.io/how-to-turn-on-avx2-in-virtualbox-guest

Everything here:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=62339

Including...

> Hyper-v competes for resources and needs to be disabled. If you want
> to be absolutely sure that Hyper-v is gone then open an administrator
> command console and type "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off". Note
> that this changed a boot option, hence it will only take effect on
> next boot. So make sure to fully power down and reboot the host after
> changing the Hyper-v setting.
>
> On some Windows hosts with an EFI BIOS, DeviceGuard or CredentialGuard
> may be active by default, and interferes with OS level virtualization
> apps in the same way that Hyper-v does. These features also need to be
> disabled. On Pro versions of Windows you can do this using gpedit.msc
> (set Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative
> Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based
> Security to Disabled. CredentialGuard is a subset of DeviceGuard, so
> disabling the former should be enough. If you cannot use gpedit for
> some reason then the equivalent registry hack is to find the key
> HKLM|SYSTEM|CurrentControlSet|Control|DeviceGuard|EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity|Enabled
> and set it to 0.
>
> On Win10 hosts, check Settings -> Device Security > Core Isolation
> Details and make sure settings in this panel are turned off, reboot
> the host from power down if you needed to make changes. "Core
> isolation [includes] security features available on your device that
> use virtualization-based security" ...which is why they can interfere
> with VirtualBox.

How can I get solana-test-validator working on Ubuntu on my machine in this VM?

Thanks